Is there a faster way to get elements in a list that are not in an existing list
I am placing pins on a map. When the user scrolls or zooms out, I now have additional pins to place. I first do a query to get all entities in the new map extent. I next need to remove from that list all pins already on the map.
// this gets the properties of all existing pins
var listEventPins = EntitiesDataSource.Shapes
    .Where(s => ReferenceEquals(s.Properties["Type"], _typeEvent))
    .Select(s => s.Properties);

// paramData.EventData is the list of all entities in the new map extent.
// this builds a list of all entities that are not already on the map - which is listEventPins
listEvents = paramData.EventData
    .Where(e => listEventPins.All(p => Convert.ToInt64(p["UniqueId"]) != e.UniqueId))
    .ToList();

For a list of 40K existing and 40K total (case where the map extent is adding almost nothing new), most of which are already on the map, the second LINQ statement takes about 40 seconds.
Is there a more performant approach to producing this second list? I can change the first LINQ query to create a List of the Properties["UniqueId"] entries and I'm sure that will help some. But is there a different approach to this that will be significantly faster?

Don't know about speed, but can't you use !Any and = instead?

The Linq is also converting each property to long, using e.UniqueId.ToString() instead would reduce those conversions.

How about computing the diff between new and the old frame, slicing that into boxes and adding the pins for the boxes. No removing. That would save you the effort to find out which pins are already on the map but comes at the cost of up to 4 requests to "get all entities" for a box.

@Thomas I looked at using regions, but then it's 4 SQL queries and that is a bigger time hit (I measured it). Good suggestion though - thanks

I would suggest building a HashSet<Int64> of existing IDs with something like var existingPinIds = listEventPins.Select(p => Convert.ToInt64(p["UniqueId"]).ToHashSet(); and then filter the event data with .Where(e => !existingPinIds.Contains(e.UniqueId)). That should be much more efficient that the existing code that is effectively a nested loop.

.SubtractBy() may also be an option, but I have not used it before, and I am unsure if it is an easy fit for your current collections. Someone who knows it better than I might make it fit.

@TN That is perfect - thank you. If you make that an answer, happy to accept it.

Another idea would be to split listEventPins into smaller chunks, like .GroupBy(s => s.UniqueId % 10) and then paramData.EventData.Where(e => listEventPins[e.UniqueId % 10].All(...)) the idea being that with an exponential operation 10 * 4000² < 40000². And Modulo10 being just an example here. You would know the nature of your UniqueIDs better than we do and what an appropriate (cheap) operation would be to split them into n more or less equally sized groups.

@Thomas - You may not have realized it, but your UniqueId % 10 calculation operates as simple hashing function and your chunked data is now a rudimentary hash table.

I would suggest building a HashSet<Int64> of existing IDs with something like var existingPinIds = listEventPins.Select(p => Convert.ToInt64(p["UniqueId"]).ToHashSet(); and then filter the event data with .Where(e => !existingPinIds.Contains(e.UniqueId)).
That should be much more efficient that the existing code that is effectively a nested loop. Each hash set .Contains() operation has complexity O(log N), so the entire filter operation should have complexity O(N log N), compared with O(n^2) for the original code.
var existingPinIds = listEventPins
    .Select(p => Convert.ToInt64(p["UniqueId"])
    .ToHashSet();

listEvents = paramData.EventData
    .Where(e => !existingPinIds.Contains(e.UniqueId))
    .ToList();


Hashsets are specifically optimised to handle the in/out of a set question, so a good approach, but you may want to consider other optimisations, like preserving the HashSet across calls and maintaining the contents (evicting pins that are removed), rather than rebuilding it every time.
